# Import JSON variable from hierarchical file into SASS with webpack

Tags: webpack, sass

I import JSON variable values into SASS with node-sass-json-importer when the file is "flat" :

```
{
  "var1": 47
}
```

without problem. My webpack.config.js is OK.

But when I use "hierarchical" JSON file :

```
{
  "part1": {
    "var1": 12,
    "var2": 31,
  }
}
```

I am not able to do that. In the scss file :

- `$aaa: $part1` output  *sass error: (var1: 47, var2: 31) isn't a valid CSS value*
- `$aaa: $part1.var1` expect an expression after "$aaa: $part1"
- and so on ...

I fully understand the problem. But I wonder if there is a sass syntax to get var1
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution : `$aaa: map-get($part1, var1);`